# Suggested tag synonym: blogs/blogging

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

[blogs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blogs) and [blogging](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blogging) seem to be basically similar in content. In principle, the former could be about reading blogs and the latter writing them, but I doubt that distinction would survive. Also, [blog](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blog) is already a synonym for [blogging](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blogging). I suggest making [blogs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blogs) a synonym for [blogging](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blogging).

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me, provided there's no huge amount of work required to make the change. For my info: Does this need to be done manually (i.e. finding each `blogging` instance and manually replacing it with `blogs`)? Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @boehj - doing it manually is an option, however that requires heading over to each post and editing it to change the tags. This results in all edited questions to appear on the homepage. ♦ can perform mass retags which will not bump up the questions

Comment: @Sathya - Awesome. Very handy to know.

Comment: @Sathya: Can't 10ks do so too?

Comment: @Hello71 Mass retags is not available to 10k..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, added a synonym mapping for [blogging](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blogging) ← [blogs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blogs)

```
updating post history, 89 rows affected
updating posts, 69 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 32 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [blogging] and [blogs] complete!
Tag Synonym blogs -> blogging was approved!
```